# Can't map fetched data from custom useFetch() hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I created a custom useFetch() hook so I can make my code more dynamic and less repetitive. The problem is that I can't display my data in App.js.

I get these errors:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').
>
> react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Can't perform a React state
> update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a
> memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and
> asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I did a console.log(genres) to see if there are any errors from my custom hook, but it works fine, logs all the genres. The problem is caused as soon as I try to display my data using the map method.

CodeSandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-meadow-z9xxrk?file=/src/App.js:0-418)

useFetch.js

```
import { useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ACTIONS = {
  API_REQUEST: "api-request",
  FETCH_DATA: "fetch-data",
  ERROR: "error",
};

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

function reducer(state, { type, payload }) {
  console.log(payload);
  switch (type) {
    case ACTIONS.API_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, data: [], loading: true };
    case ACTIONS.FETCH_DATA:
      return { ...state, data: payload, loading: false };
    case ACTIONS.ERROR:
      return { ...state, data: [], error: payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function useFetch(url) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.API_REQUEST });
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.FETCH_DATA, payload: res.data });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.ERROR, payload: e.error });
      });
  }, [url]);
  return state;
}

export default useFetch;
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";

export default function App() {
  const BASE_URL =
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${API_KEY}";
  const { data: genres, loading, error } = useFetch(BASE_URL);
  console.log(genres);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {genres.genres.map((genre) => (
        <div key={genre.id}>{genre.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does `genres` has  a key named `genres`? Wouldn't it be `genres.map...` instead `genres.genres.map`?

Comment: The `data` is already stored in a `genres` array, from `data: genres`.
That's why I'm accessing it using `genres.genres`.

Comment: @FerToasted If I scrap the whole dynamic aspect of the custom useFetch hook, and just do a normal hook with useReducer and useEffect, the code works perfectly.
That's why I'm not sure what's happening, because to my eye, everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial state has `data` as an array:

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};
```

And your `App` component is trying to read the property `genres` on that array as soon as it loads. There is no property on an array with that name, so `genres.genres` is undefined, and the map call on it will throw an error.

I would initialise `initialState.data` as `{genres: []}`, by passing the data container as another argument to your hook rather than hardcoding it into the hook file.

```
function useFetch(url, data) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {...initialState, data});
  ...
}
```

```
const { data: genres, loading, error } = useFetch(BASE_URL, {genres: []});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.
Now it makes a lot of sense what was happening.